# Allowed memory size of

Tags: php, wordpress

"Allowed memory size of 138412032 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)"
ive got this error on WordPress Admin site - what thats mean???

Comment: what are you doing there if 130MB+ is not enough for you?!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**It**](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%2Bwordpress+Allowed+memory+size+of+bytes+exhausted&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)'s a PHP memory issue [**covered in the Wordpress documentation**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP).

[**Here is a discussion of the same**](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-2) on the [**Wordpress Support Forum**](http://wordpress.org/support/).

Basically, WP is using too much memory. You can adjust the amount of memory for specifically WP within the **wp-config.php** file using, for example,:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
```

To set the limit to 96MB.

From the manual:

> Please note, this setting may not work if your host does not allow for increasing the PHP memory limit--in that event, contact your host to increase the PHP memory limit. Also, note that many hosts set the PHP limit at 8MB.