# Fatal error, Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: wordpress, memory, fatal-error

I have been getting a fatal error message, `Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted`, I have upgraded memory to no avail.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)
in /home/content/85/7866685/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1383
```

Comment: Your program/script has been consuming too much memory. Please try to figure out where your code dies. I suggest you using `echo 'text';die();` things to try around a section of statements until you find the culprit.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without additional background information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very typical WordPress issue; you should search first for existing answers before asking the question, such as " [Allowed memory size of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463276/allowed-memory-size-of) "

Using [FTP](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients) you can try increasing the memory for PHP and Wordpress in several different ways:

1) You can edit the memory_limit line in your php.ini (if you have access to that file) to increase memory to 64M:

`memory_limit = 64M;`

2) If you can't get to the php.ini file, add this line at the top of your .htaccess file:

`php_value memory_limit 64M`

If that doesn't work or throws a "500 Internal Server Error", delete the line from .htaccess.

3) Try adding the 'define" line below in your [wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) file a few lines of white space below the opening  `<?php`

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

If none of those work, your host probably doesn't allow memory allocation overrides. You're stuck with what they give.